# Dynamic Waveform Creation While Running in a Domain

Tags: redhawksdr

I am trying to connect the USRP_UHD device to the FM_mono_demo waveform.  The waveform's component that connects to the USRP_UHD is the TuneFilterDecimate.  The USRP_UHD outputs 16-bit integers while the TuneFilterDecimate computers requires float values.

The fix is to add the DataConverter component at the beginning of the FM_mono_demo waveform.

I am going to be experimenting with a different sdr whose 'device' output floats, making the original waveform correct.

Therefore I need to have two versions of the FM_mono_demo waveform, the original and one modified with the DataConverter component.

A better solution would be to launch the DataConverter component, if needed, using python and connect it to the first component of the waveform.

There is a method to launchComponent within the sandbox, but I cannot find a way to do so within a domain.

An idea would be to create two waveforms.  One would be the main waveform and the second would consist of components that could be accessed and connected to the main waveform.

This leads to the idea that multiple waveforms could be connected at run-time to allow for dynamic configuration.  There is a lot going on with this question.  Maybe I overlooked an obvious way to solve my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rather broad, but I think I can point you in the right direction.

It seems as though you're dealing with two issues:

1. Moving from sandbox to domain
2. Dealing with multiple devices

For problem 1), I recommend you dig further into the manual, specifically this section: [Redhawk Manual: The Runtime Environment](https://redhawksdr.org/2.2.0/manual/runtime-environment/).

For problem 2), you can find more information in the manual in this section: [Redhawk Manual: Working with Devices](https://redhawksdr.org/2.2.0/manual/devices/). That section includes specifying a particular hardware device and running components with Redhawk devices (proxies to the actual hardware device).

I recommend you start with those steps and post specific questions as you run into issues. You didn't actually ask a question here, but I think your confusion lies within understanding the Redhawk architecture itself.